# Exception : Too many open files

Tags: java, exception

I am using following java code in my application:

```
protected String encryptContact(Long contactId) {
        if (contactId != null) {
            EncryptionFactoryBean enbe = new EncryptionFactoryBean(String.valueOf(contactId), "/etc/test/encrypt.properties");
            try {
                enbe.SetProperties();
                return (String) enbe.getObject();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In EncryptionFactoryBean.java

```
public void setProperties()
            throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(textToEncrypt, "encryption text cannot be null");
        encryptionProperties = loadFile(encryptionFile);                  

        super.setProperties();
    }

    protected Properties loadFile(String filename)
            throws IOException {
        Properties properties = null;
        if (StringUtils.hasText(filename)) {
            File file = new File(filename);
            if (file.exists()) {
                FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
                properties = new Properties();
                properties.load(fi);
                fi.close();
            }
        }
        return properties;
    }
```

On running the application, I am getting following error -

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /etc/test/encrypt.properties (Too many open files)

It is not possible to increase the file limit in the application. Is there any way to fix this issue? Is it possible to close the file handler through **`finally`**  ?

Console log error :

```
[org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint] Socket accept failed java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:404)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:61)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:352)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Most likely you don't close files properly somewhere in your application. This is not necessarily in the code you have shown.

Comment: But the exception shows "FileNotFoundException: /etc/test/encrypt.properties" . This code is the only place where we are using  /etc/test/encrypt.properties. If we add a finally and then close the file, will it work?

Comment: You get a "Too many open files", `/etc/test/encrypt.properties` is just the last straw that breaks the camel's back.

Comment: Oh! Can you help me to find out how can we find out the files which are open and not closed in the code ?

Comment: Files can be considered a resource the same way as threads and streams. They needs to be managed. Remember to close the file when you are done. Keeping the file open will also prevent other apps to manage the content.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably during the process of `new EncryptionFactoryBean(String, String)` you have something similar to

```
Properties props = new Properties();
Reader inStream = new FileReader("/etc/test/encrypt.properties");
props.load(inStream);
```

As the Javdoc of [Properties.load(Reader)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-) / [Properties.load(InputStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-) mention

> The specified stream remains open after this method returns.

You need to close the stream yourself. For example like:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
try (Reader inStream = new FileReader("/etc/test/encrypt.properties")) {
    props.load(inStream);
}
```

Comment: in my code, is following code will work? 
finally { enbe.close }

Comment: @Futuregeek You should consider to use the [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement at the place where the properties file is read. I can't tell if `finally { enbe.close(); }` would work in your example. 1.) I don't know if your class `EncryptionFactoryBean` has a `close()` method. 2.) Assuming it exist. I don't know how the close of the properties file is implemented.